# The new Parenting Help Center

Tags: discussion

Stackexchange has recently rolled out a new [Help Center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/helpcenter) for our site (all stackexchange sites have gotten one).  I encourage everyone to check it out!

As part of the new look and feel, we now have the ability to directly update some of the content, to better fit what the community feels is the ideal presentation to new users.

From what I've seen, the specific areas we can customize are in the ["About" or "Take the Tour" page](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/about).  The ones I've found so far are:

- The initial "Welcome to Parenting Stack Exchange" text:

  > Parenting Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for parents, grandparents, nannies and others with a parenting role. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about parenting.
- The sample question displayed in "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" and "Tags make it easy to find interesting questions" (Currently they display [How should I respond to a child asking to have as much spending money as her friends do?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/1006/420))
- The "Ask About..." section, under "Get answers to practical, detailed questions":

  > - Specific issues with parenting
  > - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
- The "Don't Ask About..." section, under "Get answers to practical, detailed questions":

  > - Anything not directly related to parenting
  > - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
  > - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer
- The entire ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic) page

Please point out any other areas we can edit that I may have missed, either by editing the question, or in a comment to the question.

Please post answers if you have specific changes you'd like to make in one or more of the areas where we have direct choices.

If you see something that should be changed that isn't something we can directly edit, or if you feel significant changes/new pages specific to our parenting site would be beneficial, please start a new meta question using the [feature-request](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [help-center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help-center) tags.

For an introduction to the intent behind the new Help Center, as well as the main discussion/questions/answers, please visit the original [meta.stackoverflow announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center).

Don't forget to vote for or against any of the edits suggested in answers to this discussion below!  If you downvote to indicate that you disagree with the suggestion, please consider either posting your own answer suggesting a better edit, or leaving a comment explaining your concerns.  Remember: downvotes in meta do not impact reputation!

Comment: Mods can also edit the entire ["What topics can I ask about?"](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic) page - that replaces the old faq#questions section.