# Why is the list of acceptable topics so hard to find?

Tags: feature-request

I saw a user vote to close a question as off-topic the other day. Which lead me to trying to find the list of topics deemed acceptable for the parenting site. Which lead to an awful lot of frustration:

- I could not find any link to it on the front page.
- I could not find any link to it on the "Ask Question" page.
- I could not find it with a search of Parenting Meta.

So let's just say that it's not obvious you have to go into the help center to find the link to acceptable topics. Why is there not a big fat link on the "Ask Question" page? It already says "Is your question about parenting?" and I would expect a link very close to that as that's when you'll need the information the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry about your frustration. You're right, it's not obvious. You're not alone. So please allow me to go over it for future visitors. All Stack Exchange sites use basically the same format, so learning one will help users across the network.

Above the "Ask Question" option, there's a black bar with the word *help*. (On the "Ask Question" page, there is a sidebar with a "visit the help center" option. That would have helped as well.) Tap that and you have options, one of which is the [Help Center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) ("Detailed answers to any questions you might have".) If you select that, you will find most of what you want to under [Asking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), including "What topics can I ask about here?"

On that page, you'll see

> We welcome questions on topics like these:
>
> - matters of upbringing,
> - safety considerations,
> - food and feeding,
> - health and hygiene,
> - development and growth,
> - language development,
> - behavior and social skills,
> - discipline and punishment,
> - childrens'/family games for developmental purposes or parental sanity.

You'll also see what is off-topic.

Also, if you go to meta and simply type *help* in the search box, you will be guided to [this post](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/513/9327). It's very helpful.

At the bottom of the front page, you'll see another opportunity to find help with more options.

It would be great if the answers to this question were easier to find, but there's nothing individual sites can do about it. This is a familiar problem across all Stack Exchange sites, and as very, very little variation is allowed, this (how to make the help section easier to find/etc.?) might better be taken up on Stack Exchange Meta, as they deal with design problems and all issues that affect all SE sites.

Again, I apologize for your frustration; it's quite understandable.

Comment: No need to apologize, it's not your fault and I did eventually find the information. But I did not know this was forced to be the same on all SE sites as they do have some layout variation. I thought this might have been one of them. I'll head over to SE meta to see if there has been discussion of that topic.