# Any recent changes to editable sections of the Help Center?

Tags: support

**Are there any recent changes to editable sections of the Help Center on Parenting.SE?**

See this thread about the related changes on Stack Overflow:

Feedback and suggestions for editable section of Help Center - Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390769/feedback-and-suggestions-for-editable-section-of-help-center

> I've recently noticed that moderators are now able to edit a section
>   below the Help Center's search box on the landing page. For reference,
>   two other sites that are using this section as well are Hardware Recs
>   and Code Review.
>
> While I have added in a simple section for starters, thoughts and
>   suggestions are welcome.

**Compare these:**

Help Center - Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Help Center - Parenting Stack Exchange: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help

**SEE ALSO:**

The new Parenting Help Center - Parenting Meta Stack Exchange: [The new Parenting Help Center](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/513/the-new-parenting-help-center)

Why is the list of acceptable topics so hard to find? - Parenting Meta Stack Exchange: [Why is the list of acceptable topics so hard to find?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/why-is-the-list-of-acceptable-topics-so-hard-to-find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - there is a section on the [help center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) which is editable (at least, it has an edit link which I can click on and takes me to an editing page; I didn't verify it works, but I would assume so?).  Perhaps we should have a question/answer for what to put in it?

Comment: Re: *Perhaps we should have a question/answer for what to put in it?* Yes, this would be very helpful! Perhaps one of the moderators could start this thread and ask for suggestions from both new and experienced users? The editable portions can be seen only by moderators or maybe by users above certain rep, by design. So it might be helpful to point out in that new thread **which parts of the Help Center are now editable.** Either a screenshot or a brief description with links, whichever is easier.

Comment: @TimurShtatland You're certainly welcome to start such a thread, with any suggestion you would like to make!  The only part that is editable is the part between the search box and "Find out more about...".