# Feedback and suggestions for the editable section of the Help Center?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, scope, moderation

**What useful info should we add to the Parenting Stack Exchange [Help Center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help)?**

The part between the `search` box and `"Find out more about..."` is now [editable by moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390769). I posted a short possible addition as an answer below. Please feel free to edit and/or add other answers.

**Examples of SE sites with useful info in the Help Center editable section:**

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help)
- [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help)
- [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help)

**SEE ALSO:**

- [Any recent changes to editable sections of the Help Center?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1363)
- [Feedback and suggestions for editable section of Help Center - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390769)

Answer (score 1):

**Cannot find the answer?** Search for or ask a question about Parenting Stack Exchange on [**Meta**](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com), for example [Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ).](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=votes) - [Policies.](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy?sort=votes) - [How to ask a question?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions?sort=votes) - [How to prevent your question from being closed as off-topic?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope?sort=votes) - [Best practices.](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion?sort=votes)

**Stack Exchange** (general info - anything not covered above): [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931)